# Need Query to Track Multiple Prices and coresponding Stock from 2 Tables

Tags: sql, vb.net, join, casting

I need help in building a SQL query to retrieve data from 2 tables having multiple prices and different quantity. This query should sort out the distinct value of Price corresponding Quantity left.

The Sample Tables are as follows:

TABLE NAME: **DETAILPURCHASE**

```html
ITEMID       MRP SALEPRICE   COST  QTY Purchased
1       100    100      80        125
1       100    100      80        125
1       100     95      80        120
1       220    210      10        100
1       220    220     100         50
1       200    200     100         50
1       100     95      80         60
1       100     95      80         60
2        80     80      50         50
2        80     80      50         50
2        80     80      50         89
2        50     50      40         89
2        50     50      40         78
1       200    200     100         78
1       100     95      80         50
```

TABLE NAME: **DETAILSALE**

```html
ITEMID MRP SALEPRICE COSTPRICE QTY Sold
1 100    95            80          150
1 100   100            80          200
1 200   200           100          128
```

Resultant Table: Sample **For Item ID: 1**

```html
MRP SALEPRICE COSTPRICE QTY LEFT
100 100            80        50
100 95            80       140
220 210            10       100
220 220           100        50
```

For Item ID 1: Sale of QTY:128 made for MRP:200 Hence Total Purchase = Total Sale making it '0'. Hence this row **shouldn't** be visible

Resultant Table: Sample **For Item ID: 2**

```html
MRP SALEPRICE COSTPRICE QTY LEFT
80 80            50        189
50 50            40        167
```

Since no sale is made on ItemID 2 All records should be visible

```
select  DP.[PRICE],
        DP.[PRICE],
        DP.[CP],
        DP.[MRP],
        SUM(CAST(DP.[QUANTITY] AS NUMERIC(18,2))) - SUM(CAST(DS.[QTY] AS NUMERIC(18,2))) 
FROM    [iBillDB].[dbo].[DETAILPURCHASES] DP , 
        [iBillDB].[dbo].[DETAILSALE] DS 
WHERE DP.ITEMN = 1 
AND DP.ITEMN= DS.ITEMN 
AND DP.PRICE = DS.PRICE 
GROUP BY DP.[PRICE],DP.[PRICE],DP.[CP],DP.[MRP]
```

Which returns Nothing / Empty Rows

Please help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try displaying all the columns with the join condition only. Remove the `DP.ITEMN = 1 ` and the `sum` and the `group by`

Comment: It has to sum up Quantity for duplicate MRP, Selling Prices showing in single row. I dont think Removing sum can give my solution

Comment: It is not for solution, just debugging. Look at the result, you probably dont have any line, therefore, it means your where condition is a problem.

Comment: I tried left join as:select dp.mrp,dp.PRICE,dp.PRICE,dp.CP,sum(cast(dp.[QUANTITY] as numeric(18,2)))-sum(cast(ds.[QTY] as numeric(18,2))) from [iBillDB].[dbo].[DETAILPURCHASES] dp left join  [iBillDB].[dbo].[DETAILSALE] ds on dp.MRP = ds.MRP group by dp.mrp,dp.PRICE,dp.CP Still not good with quatity caluclation returning as NULL